# Delphi 2010 & MySQL : Korean string is broken in homepage

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-2010, unicode-string

I am developing network communication system using Delphi 2010.
Server side has server application and homepage that display informations from clients.
All string data(including Korean) are saved in mysql DB. 
DB was created by utf8(Character set), utf8_unicode_ci().
And I used UNIDAC components for mysql connection.
In application, displaying Korean string is OK, but in Homepage the Korean string is showed broken.

What is the correct solution? By searching google, there are amount of similar articles. But I can't decide what is right way.
Please help me.
below is my code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sql: string;
begin

  sql := 'INSERT INTO test.test_table (name) VALUES (' + QuotedStr('가나다') + ');';
  UniQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  UniQuery1.SQL.Add(sql);
  UniQuery1.ExecSQL;

  sql := 'SELECT * FROM test.test_table';
  UniQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  UniQuery1.SQL.Add(sql);
  UniQuery1.ExecSQL;

end;
```